# Send HTML email asp

Tags: email, asp-classic, vbscript

I want to add some html in an email. I've tried the following.

```
vFromName = "someone"
vFromAddress = "someemail"
vTo = "recipient"
vSubject="someSubject"
vBodyofemail = "<html><table><tr><td><b>SomeText</b></td></tr></table></html>"

Call SendMail()

sub SendMail()
  'change to address of your own SMTP server
  strHost = "mail.internal.rouses.com"
  Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")
  'enter valid SMTP host
  Mail.Host = strHost
  'From eMail address
  Mail.FromName = vFromName
  'From address
  Mail.From = vFromAddress 
  'To eMail address
  Mail.AddAddress vTo
  'message subject
  Mail.Subject = vSubject
  'message body
  Mail.Body = vBodyOfEmail
 Mail.Send
end sub
```

How can i do  this? I've tried Mail.HtmlBody but that doesn't work either. The email is sent but all i see are the tags where the html is.

Comment: What doesn't work?  Does the e-mail send and you see html, or do you not get an e-mail at all?

Comment: The email is sent. I just see the html-tags though...not what they are supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.aspemail.com/manual_02.html) you need to set the **IsHTML** flag to true.

```
strHTML = "Hello world"

Mail.IsHTML = True
Mail.Body = "<HTML><BODY><CENTER>" & strHTML & "</CENTER></BODY></HTML>"
```

Comment: This worked. My issue was that this function is in a few places and the one I was editing was not the correct function called. Thank you.

Comment: But then how is the plain-text (within the same message) defined?

Comment: You would simply put this at the end of the html string:
& chr(10) & chr(13)& chr(10) & chr(13) _
then
&"plain-text"

it works.

Comment: Hmmm, I doubt a few newlines will make Persits.MailSender generate a MIME Boundary. Did you actually test that with a few clients? I can imagine that any text added after the closing </HTML> tag will not be shown in HTML mode, but I doubt the HTML version will be hidden when viewing the message as plain text...

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this line above the send call.

```
Mail.IsHTML = true
```

Without it, the Mail object defaults to standard text and whatever is typed into the Body property will be rendered in the email as text.

Comment: This worked. My issue was that this function is in a few places and the one I was editing was not the correct function called. Thank you.  C. Ross answered it first so I'll give him the answer. but I'll give you +1

Comment: The function being in a few places sounds a bit like a code smell :)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but shouldn't all messages include plain text as well? Without plain text, you'll surely get a higher spam score.

(And people like myself prefer to switch to plain text if your HTML/CSS is not rendered well. See [Guide to CSS support in email clients (2008)](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), and the list at [the Email Standards Project](http://www.email-standards.org/).)

Comment: ...but then how would you put both the plain text and the HTML in the Mail.Body property? I wonder if Persits.MailSender is the way to go.